# open route in a sidepage using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework

I'm building a back office using Quasar. I would like to be able to open routes in what I would call a sidepage (for the lack of a better better word... maybe you have one?).

Opening a route in this sidepage would render the component requested without decoration (like menus).
This route could potentially however be opened directly in a new window (not in a sidepage) with decoration.

From this sidepage, I would like to be able to open another sidepage, and so on.

This is basically what I'd like to do (https://tagmanager.google.com/) :

[image: sidepage]

I've literally no clue how to do that. I'm trying to build a component that would take a route, create a sidepage, size it correctly (as you can see the second sidepage is smaller than the first one) )and open the route in it but I fail to do so.
Any clue where to start or any idea on a component that would do that already ? I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for your component using the path in the router options.

```
const route = this.$router.options.routes.find(
      (route) => !!route?.path?.includes("route/to/display")
    )
this.component = route?.component;
```

And then display it using `component` tag.

```
<component :is="component" />
```